# HTML audio can't set currentTime

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am using Chrome. In my dev tools console, I tried the following:

[image]

Everything works as expected except last line. Why can't I set `currentTime` on it?

Also in general, I am finding this whole HTML5 Audio thing to not be very reliable. Is there a robust javascript wrapper that fallsback to flash ?

Comment: Audio has a 'loadedmetadata' event that fires when the src has been loaded

Comment: @echopeak is there a working example I can look at? I am more interested in the `seek` event as I want to play the audio from a different start point.

Comment: can you provide a link to download the audio?

Comment: @Rajat _"Why cant I set `currentTime` on it?"_ Cannot reproduce

Comment: I am facing the same issue. It's working on a piece of code, but when i integrate it in a Django application, it fails. It works on Firefox but not on Google Chrome. Video / Audio file doesn't matter, it happens with any file i try on the code. The time i am trying to seek to is less than the duration of the video.

Comment: @atb00ker any answer on why this happens when starting a django server?  I am experiencing the same, also only when accessing the same files via a django server.

Comment: @AdagioMolto The answer here helped me find the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42977670/6410464

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to do something like this (if you use jQuery)

```
$('#elem_audio').bind('canplay', function() {
  this.currentTime = 10;
});
```

or in Javascript

```
var aud = document.getElementById("elem_audio");
aud.oncanplay = function() {
    aud.currentTime = 10;
};
```

The reason behind for this setup is you need to make sure the **audio is ready to play**.

Comment: Also you can use `seeked` event. [Here is example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) in the end of page.

Comment: So i tried adding `x.addEventListener('seeked', function () { x.play()  })` right before updating the `currentTime` to `10` and the result is the same. When the audio plays, it starts from 0.

Comment: @Rajat I don't know if this will work for  you but you tried also the event `canplaythrough`?

Comment: @OlgaReal Actually `canplay` works. I was doing `.bind('canplay', function() { this.currentTime = 10; this.play() });` and that doesn't work. `play()` needs to be outside the handler.

Comment: This solution makes chatty. but if you do the following it works on chrome/


`
var aud = document.getElementById("audiobar")

aud.load()

aud.currentTime=1

aud.load()
`

-// After those 3 sequence setting currentTime works consistently>

The sequence is (1) load (2) set currentTime (3) load 

horrible hack

Answer (score 16):

Check your HTTP server configuration, in my testing environment ( Chrome 69 on Mac OS) setting *currentTime* property of *audio element* works only when the audio source is served by a HTTP server support *persistent connection*.

If the HTTP server you used support persistent connection, you will found (in Chrome DevTool) the Connection field of response headers of your audio source be **keep-alive**. By contrast if the audio source is served by a persistent connection incompatible server, there will be **no Connection field** in response headers.

The status code of your audio source HTTP request will be a reference too, **206 Partial Content** for persistent connection supported server, **200 OK** for an inferior one.

Comment: I can confirm the Webserver can be the reason for this issue.
But in my test environment, both my local DEV server and my live server have a `Connection: keep-alive` in the _Response Headers_. I see the difference in the `Status Code: 200` vs `Status Code: 206`. Additional I see in the working live server a `Accept-Ranges: bytes`, which I am missing in my DEV server.

Comment: I had to make sure `Accept-Ranges: bytes` was present in the response headers - that did the trick!

Comment: This happened to me while serving a small mp3 file from Spring Boot 2. Thanks for avoiding me headaches!!

Comment: thanks @brianarpie, I had to change my context.Response.Headers.Add("Accept-Ranges", "0-" + size);  to context.Response.Headers.Add("Accept-Ranges", "bytes 0-" + size); So yeah, I did append the bytes infront of the range string, and that did the trick! One thing i need to point out is that, i didn't have an issue when i used the prior code block for video streaming. It is weird that for audio streaming, i need to add "bytes" infront of the range string.

Comment: this worked... can someone explain why??? @brianarpie

Comment: @Ji_in_coding Thanks a lot! Your code snippet saved me lots of neurons, from the few I still have left. :-D

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, and the reason was missing headers on the mp3 file, like:

`Content-Length, Content-Range, Content-Type`

Comment: For Chrome 70, I also needed to add "Accept-Range: bytes", even though the files were small and everything were piped down on init connection.

Comment: How to add this headers on the example showed in the question?

Answer (score 8):

> Why cant I set `currentTime` on it?

Could not reproduce `currentTime` being set to `0` after setting to `10`. Is `18.mp3` duration less than `10`?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "/assets/audio/18.mp3", true);
request.responseType = "blob";    
request.onload = function() {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    var audio = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(this.response));
    audio.load();
    audio.currentTime = 10;
    audio.play();
  }
}
request.send();
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lg5L4qso/3/

Comment: This was the solution I used. Create an object url, then set the source.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem after I'd started to use the PHP Server extension to VS Code to serve my HTML/PHP local testing. The problem was resolved for me by going back to my old Abysswebserver setup.

So, it's not simply that "you can't manipulate .currentTime on locally served files" but rather that "you need to pick a server that gives you the right headers". The Status entry for my file from AbyssWebserver, for example, read "Status Code: 206 Partial Content" while the one from PHP Server read "Status Code: 200 OK".

There are other differences though so there may be more to this than just the Status entry. See https://github.com/brapifra/vscode-phpserver/issues/85, for a full header comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return to the beginning of the audio after it has been played, use `load()`.

```
// x.currentTime = 0;
x.load();
```

( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/load )

Comment: Sorry but your first affirmation is incorrect and you are misinterpreting the quote from the documentation.

Comment: @BenSouchet Thank you for your comment. Could you tell me why you think the way you do?

Comment: you can use `currentTime` to retrieve the value for example when the audio is on pause, so it's no only "used when the media **has not yet been played**".
The quote from the documentation only state that **IF** the media isn't playing, the `currentTime` indicate the current/start position for the media.
The next line form the docs is "Setting `currentTime` to a new value seeks the media to the given time, if the media is available." so you can change/update the currentTime. 
So you can `play()`, then `pause()` then edit `currentTime`, then `play()`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I saw your comment and understood the content. Therefore, I removed the first half of the description. Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: I updated my vote accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
var callaudio = audio; // the audio variable
     function fetchAudioFile() {
         var requestObj = new Request(callaudio.src, {
             method: 'GET',
             headers: {
                 'Accept-Ranges': '1000000000'
             },
             referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer'
         });

         fetch(requestObj).then(function (response) {
             returnresponse;
         }).then(async function (outcome) {
             const blob = await outcome.blob();
             const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
             callaudio.src = url;
         });
     };
     fetchAudioFile();
```

Comment: how do i set currrenttime from bufersource?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that '10' is longer that you mp3's length.

But that logs the length of mp3 instead of '0'.

Comment: No. `x.duration` returns `31`. Chrome version is 50

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for setting `currentTime` I got to work reliably was using the `onprogress` event.

```
audio.onprogress = function() {
  if (audio.currentTime == 0) {
    audio.currentTime = 10;
  }
}
```

Comment: This creates an infinite loop because when `audio.currentTime = xxx` it is immediately set to `0`, causing the `audio.onprogress` to be called again, where the `audio.currentTime` is equal to `0` again. Then, everything repeats again forever.

Answer (score 0):

The solution which worked for me was not setting "src" on  directly, but use  with type attribute, maybe type attribute is helping browser some way.