# It always becomes 0 regardless of what is set to the currentTime of the audio tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a player that can play music with a Web browser, but I am in trouble because I can not change the playback position.  (currentTime)

Specifically, even if we assign a numeric value to the currentTime of mp3 music read with the audio tag of html 5, it will always be 0.

```
   <audio id="audio" class="back-player"  preload="auto">
    <source src="/audios/<?= $source ?>" type="<?= $mime ?>" />
  </audio>
```

**version**

- HTML5
- jQuery: 2.23

[image: click input]

**not working**

```
 $(document).on('change','.js-play-position',function(e) {
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  val = $(this).val();
  val = Number(val);
  audio.currentTime = val;
});
```

**working**

```
$('.js-play').click(function()
{
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    audio.play();
    $('.js-play').addClass('hidden');
    $('.js-pause').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

**working**

```
 $( '.js-volume' ).change( function () {
        var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    var val = $(this).val();
    var val = (val*0.01);
    audio.volume = val;
  } );
```

I do not know why the only currentTime does not work. Is it wrong to write?
please teach me.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .audioplayer{display:none;}
  #audio-area {width: 100vw; position: relative;}
  #audio-area:before {
    z-index: 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  }
  .audio-container{position: relative; z-index:2;}
  .audio__tag{color: #FFF; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 10px;}
  .audio__tag:before{font-family:'FontAwesome'; color: #FFF;  content: "\f02b";}
  .audio__title{font-size:14px; padding: 0.5em; color: #FFF; background-color: #000;}
  .audio__name{display: inline-block; color: #FFF; font-size:12px; background-color: #000; padding: 0.5em;}
  .audio__controll{width:100%; border-radius: 3px; background-color: #FFF; opacity: 0.9; margin-bottom: 10px; overflow: hidden;}
  /*　再生エリア */
  .audio-loader{
    position: absolute;
    top: 33%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 999;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .fa-spinner:before {font-size: 50px;}
  input[type=range].controll-play-position{width:90%; margin: 20px 5%;}
  .controll-position{display:flex;  justify-content: space-between; width: 80%; margin: 10px 10%; list-style: none; padding-left:0;}
  .position-now{display: block; width: 90%; margin: 10px 5% 10px 2%; height: 1em;}
  .position-start{margin-left: 5%;}
  .position-end{position:absolute; right: 5%; margin-right: 3%;}
  .controll-position__link{color: #000;}
  .controll-position__back{text-align:center; font-size:11px; font-weight: bold;}
  .controll-position__10sback{text-align:center; font-size:11px;font-weight: bold;}
  .controll-position__pause{text-align:center; font-size:11px;font-weight: bold;}
  .controll-position__play{text-align:center; font-size:11px;font-weight: bold;}
  .controll-position__10sforward{text-align:center; font-size:11px;font-weight: bold;}
  .controll-position__forward{text-align:center; font-size:11px;font-weight: bold;}
  .controll-position__back:before {font-family:FontAwesome; content: "\f049";display: block; position:relative; font-size:30px;font-weight: 400;}
  .controll-position__10sback:before {font-family:FontAwesome; content: "\f04a";display: block; position:relative; font-size:30px;font-weight: 400;}
  .controll-position__pause:before {font-family:FontAwesome; content: "\f04c";display: block; position:relative; font-size:30px;font-weight: 400;}
  .controll-position__play:before {font-family:FontAwesome; content: "\f04b";display: block; position:relative; font-size:30px;font-weight: 400;}
  .controll-position__10sforward:before {font-family:FontAwesome; content: "\f04e";display: block; position:relative; font-size:30px;font-weight: 400;}
  .controll-position__forward:before {font-family:FontAwesome; content: "\f050";display: block; position:relative; font-size:30px;font-weight: 400;}
  .controll-bottom{width:90%; margin: 20px 5%; overflow: auto;}
  .controll-speed{font-size: 11px; padding-left: 0; padding-right:10px;}
  @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {.controll-speed{font-size: 9px;}}
  .controll-speed-list{list-style: none; display:flex; padding-left:0; padding-right:0; -webkit-justify-content: space-between; /* Safari */justify-content: space-between;}
  .controll-speed__minus{font-weight:bold; padding: 0 2vw;}
  .controll-speed__minus:active{background-color: #E5E5E5; transition-property: background;  transition-duration: 0.5s transition-delay: 0.5s transition-timing-function: ease-in;}
  .controll-speed__minus:before {font-family:FontAwesome; content: "\f068";display: block; position:relative; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size:20px;font-weight:400;}
  .controll-speed__refresh{font-weight:bold;}
  .controll-speed__refresh:active{background-color: #E5E5E5; transition-property: background;  transition-duration: 0.5s transition-delay: 0.5s transition-timing-function: ease-in;}
  .controll-speed__refresh:before {font-family:FontAwesome; content: "\f01e";display: block; position:relative;margin-bottom: 5px; font-size:20px; text-align:center;font-weight:400;}
  .controll-speed__plus{font-weight:bold; padding: 0 2vw;}
  .controll-speed__plus:active{background-color: #E5E5E5; transition-property: background;  transition-duration: 0.5s transition-delay: 0.5s transition-timing-function: ease-in;}
  .controll-speed__plus:before {font-family:FontAwesome; content: "\f067";display: block; position:relative;margin-bottom: 5px; font-size:20px;font-weight:400;}
  .controll-volume{width: 50%; padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0; padding-top: 10%;}
  @media only screen and (min-width: 551px) {.controll-volume{padding-top: 5%;}}
  input[type=range].controll-volume__main{display:inline-block; width:80%; position:absolute; top:40%; left: 20%;}
  .icon-volume-down{position: absolute; top: 10%; left: 10px;}
  @media only screen and (min-width: 551px) {.icon-volume-down{left: 0px;}}
  .icon-volume-down i{font-size: 15px;}
  .icon-volume-up{position: absolute; top: 10%; right: -23px;}
  @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {.icon-volume-up{right: -19px;}}
  @media only screen and (min-width: 551px) {.icon-volume-up{right: -30px;}}
  .icon-volume-up i{font-size: 15px;}

  input[type=range] {-webkit-appearance:none; background-color:#95989A; height: 2px;}
  input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb{ -webkit-appearance:none; height:17px; width:17px; border-radius: 17px; background-color:#555; border: none;}

  /* アイコンたち */
  .fal,.fas{font-family: FontAwesome; font-style: normal; font-size: 20px;}
  .audio__actions{display: flex; display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */ text-align: center; width: 100%;}
  .actions{width: 20%; padding: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px; position:relative;}
  .actions--active{background-color: #FFF; border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;}
  .fa-heart:before {color: #fff;}
  .fa-comment:before {color: #fff;}
  .fa-comment--active:before {color: #00357E;}
  .fa-bookmark {color: #fff;}
  .fa-bookmark--active:before {color: #00357E;}
  .fa-repeat:before,.fa-repeat-1:before{color: #FFF;}
  .fa-file-alt{color: #FFF;}
  .audio-comment__num{font-size: 13px; color: #FFF; position:absolute; top: 10px; right: 3px;}
  .audio-action__string{color: #FFF; font-size: 1vw; margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0.5vh;}
  .audio-action__string--active{color: #00357E;}

  /*アコーディオン */
  .audio-acordion{display:none;}
  .audio-comment__title{font-size: 14px; color: #00357E;}
  .audio-comment__form{resize: none; margin-bottom: 8px;}
  .audio-comment__review-title{font-size: 16px; text-align:center; color: #000; padding-bottom: 6px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
  .review-wrapper{margin-bottom:15px; padding: 10px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE;}
  .reviewer{margin-bottom:10px;}
  .reviewer__image{display: inline-block; height:40px; width: 40px; object-fit: cover; border-radius: 40px; -webkit-border-radius: 40px; background-color: #ccc;}
  .reviewer__name{display: inline-block; margin-left: 10px;}
  .chapter-item{margin-bottom:10px; padding-bottom:10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #EBECEC;}
  .chapter-heading{display: inline-block; width: 10%; object-fit: cover; vertical-align: unset;}
  .chapter-strings{display: inline-block; margin-left: 10px; width: 85%;}
  .chapter-strings__no{font-size: 12px; color: #0B3862; margin-bottom: 5px;}
  .chapter-strings__title{font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; margin:0 0 5px; white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;}

  /* 追加コンテンツ */
  .more-contents__heading{font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; margin-bottom: 20px;}
  .audio-tabs{width: 100vw; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; margin-bottom:10px;}
  .nav>li>span.audio-tabs__list{font-size: 14px; padding:20px; margin-right: 0; border: none; color: #888585;}
  @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {.nav>li>span.audio-tabs__list{font-size: 12px;}}
  .active{border-bottom:1px solid #666;}
  .nav>li.active>span.audio-tabs__list{font-weight:bold; color: #000;}/*選択中のタブ*/
  .more-contents__podcast{width: 100%; border-bottom:1px solid #95989A;}
  .podcast-contents-wrap{margin: 0; padding: 6px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #95989A;}
  .podcast-contents__title{font-size:13px; color: #00357E; font-wight: bold; margin-bottom: 10px;}
  .podcast-contents__publish{font-size:12px; padding: 0;}
  @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {.podcast-contents__publish{font-size:9px;}}
  .podcast-contents__publish:before{font-family:FontAwesome; content:'\f133'; margin-right: 4px;}
  .podcast-contents__time{font-size:12px; padding:0; padding-left: 10px;}
  @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {.podcast-contents__time{font-size:9px;}}
  .podcast-contents__time:before{font-family:FontAwesome; content: '\f017'; margin-right: 4px;}
  .podcast-contents__likes{font-size:12px; padding: 0;}
  @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {.podcast-contents__likes{font-size:9px;}}
  .podcast-contents__likes:before{font-family:FontAwesome; content:'\f004'; margin-right: 4px; color: #F50B6B;}
  .podcast-contents__comments{font-size:12px; padding:0;}
  @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {.podcast-contents__comments{font-size:9px;}}
  .podcast-contents__comments:before{font-family:FontAwesome; content:'\f075'; margin-right: 4px; color: #003383;}
  .podcast-contents__summary{margin-top: -4px;}
  .more-summary__icon{color: #000;}
  .more-contents__pause{font-size: 18px; color: #FFF; margin-bottom: 10vh; /* for iOS */ -webkit-appearance: none; border-radius: 0; border: none;/*for Android */ background-color: #000;}
  .more-contents__pause:before{margin: 8vh 0 10px;}
  @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {.more-contents__pause:before{margin-top: 0px;}}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="ja">
<head>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
  windowWidth = $(window).width(); 
 
 $('.js-rate').click(function()
 {
  var mode = $(this).attr('rel');

  if(mode == '0')
  {
   rate = 1.0;
  }
  else if(mode == '+' && rate < 2)
  {
   rate += 0.25;
  }
  else if(mode == '-' && rate > 0.5)
  {
   rate -= 0.25;
  }
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.playbackRate = rate;
 });

 $('.js-play').click(function()
 {
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  audio.play();
  $('.js-play').addClass('hidden');
  $('.js-pause').removeClass('hidden');
 });
  
 $('.js-pause').click(function()
 {
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  audio.pause();
  $('.js-pause').addClass('hidden');
  $('.js-play').removeClass('hidden');
 });

  $( '.js-10s-back' ).click( function () {
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    audio.currentTime -= 10;
  } );

  $( '.js-10s-forward' ).click( function () {
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    audio.currentTime += 10;
  } );

  $( '.js-volume' ).change( function () {
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    var val = $(this).val();
    var val = (val*0.01);
    audio.volume = val;
  } );

  $( '.js-loop' ).click( function () {
  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    if (audio.loop == false)
    {
      audio.loop = true;
      $('[id=js-loop-icon]').removeClass('fa-repeat');
      $('[id=js-loop-icon]').addClass('fa-repeat-1');
    }else {
      audio.loop = false;
      $('[id=js-loop-icon]').addClass('fa-repeat');
      $('[id=js-loop-icon]').removeClass('fa-repeat-1');
    }
  });


    //inputの変更を再生位置に反映
    //動的に生成したDOMに関しては以下のクリックイベントを使用
    $(document).on('change','.js-play-position',function(e) {
      var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
      val = $(this).val();
      val = Number(val);
      console.log('console:val=' + val)
      audio.oncanplay = function() {
            audio.currentTime = val;
            console.log(audio.currentTime)
      };
    });

  //1秒ごとに再生位置を監視→input要素に反映
  setInterval(function(){
    //スクロール位置監視　→　コンテンツ追加読み込み
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    var time = audio.currentTime;
    $('[id=js-play-position]').val(time);
 },1000);



});

//動的に再生位置バーを生成
$(window).on("load", function(){
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    var front = '<input type="range" class="controll-play-position js-play-position" id="js-play-position" value="0" min="0" max="';
    var last = '">';
    $('[id=js-position-now]').after(front + audio.duration + last);

    //再生終了時間の計算
    var minute = Math.floor(audio.duration/60);
    minute = ( '00' + minute ).slice( -2 ); // 先頭に0を足してから2桁に整形
    var sec = Math.floor(audio.duration%60);
    sec = ( '00' + sec ).slice( -2 );
    $('[id=js-position-end]').text(minute + ':' + sec);

    //現在位置の表示
    TOTAL = Math.round(audio.duration);
    audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
        var NOW = Math.round(audio.currentTime);
        if(windowWidth < 1023){var PERCE = (NOW / TOTAL * 100 * 0.99) + '%';}
        if(windowWidth > 1023){var PERCE = (NOW / TOTAL * 100 * 0.90) + '%';}
        if(windowWidth > 1023)
        {
          $('[id=js-position-now]').css({'position':'absolute', 'left': PERCE});
        }
        if(windowWidth < 1023)
        {
          $('[id=js-position-now]').css({'position':'relative', 'left': PERCE});
        }
        //現在時間の表示
        var nowTime = Math.round(audio.currentTime);
        var min = Math.floor(nowTime / 60);
        min = ( '00' + min ).slice( -2 ); // 先頭に0を足してから2桁に整形
        var sec = nowTime % 60;
        sec = ( '00' + sec ).slice( -2 );
        $('[id=js-position-now]').text(min + ':' + sec);
    }, true);
    $("[id=js-dummy-play-position]").remove();
    $("[id=js-loader]").remove();
    $('[id=js-audio-wrap<?= $id ?>]').addClass('audio-active');

});

</script>



</head>
<body>
  <audio id="audio" class="back-player"  preload="auto">
    <source src="http://www.ne.jp/asahi/music/myuu/wave/menuettm.mp3" type="" />
  </audio>
 <section class="movie-watch hidden  visible-xs visible-sm">
    <div class="audio-loader" id="js-loader">
      <i class="far fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="audio-area" class="audio-area">
      <div class="container audio-container">
        <p class="audio__tag">   <?= $categories[0]['name'] ?></p>
        <p class="audio__title"><?= $title ?></p>
        <p class="audio__name"><?= $teacher_name ?></p>
        <div class="audio__controll">
          <span class="position-now" id="js-position-now" class="js-position-now">00:00</span>
          <input type="range" class="controll-play-position" id="js-dummy-play-position" value="0" min="0" max="">
          <span class="position-start" id="js-position-start">00:00</span>
          <span class="position-end" id="js-position-end"></span>
          <ul class="controll-position">
            <li class="controll-position__back" onclick="back(json_now.id)">前へ</li>
            <li class="controll-position__10sback js-10s-back">10秒戻る</li>
            <li class="js-play controll-position__play">　再生　</li>
            <li class="js-pause controll-position__pause hidden">一時停止</li>
            <li class="controll-position__10sforward js-10s-forward">10秒進む</li>
            <li class="controll-position__forward" onclick="next(json_now.id)">次へ</li>
          </ul>
          <div class="controll-bottom">
            <div class="controll-speed col-xs-5">
              <ul class="controll-speed-list">
              <li class="js-rate controll-speed__minus" rel="-">遅く</li>
              <li class="js-rate controll-speed__refresh" rel="0">リセット</li>
              <li class="js-rate controll-speed__plus" rel="+">早く</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="controll-volume col-xs-7">
              <span class="icon-volume-down"><i class="fal fa-volume-mute"></i></span>
              <input type="range" class="js-volume controll-volume__main" value="50" min="0" max="99">
              <span class="icon-volume-up"><i class="fal fa-volume-up"></i></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: `console.log(val)` before you set `currentTime`. Is it correct? Also, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37044134/4875631) for a possible solution.

Comment: Your range select goes from which to which values? Your media duration is how much?

Comment: yes console.log = integer.

Comment: @kaiiido my mp3.duration = 400s ~ 1000s.

Comment: `400s ~ 1000s` that is not a possible value for `MediaElement.duration`. Please be precise. What does `audio.duration` outputs in your event handler. And what does `Number(val)` outputs?

Comment: @kaiido duration = 712.   Number(val) = 280.

Comment: Explanation was not enough.
The thing you want to do is to move the playback position to the clicked position

Comment: Can you share more of your code so that you could create a working snippet ?

Comment: @Takit lsy sorry. snippet does not working.  I so not working in php

Comment: Well, I was wondering that you can remove the PHP parts to get a snippet with "fixed" values.

Comment: @Takit   snipett create but incomplete

Comment: You didn't remove the PHP parts in the scripts located in your HTML! :)

Comment: @Takit Sorry, the snippet does not work.