# How do I change the time of an audio buffer source in the Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

If I had an audio element, I could use something like
`audioElement.currentTime=5;`

But how do I set the time for an audio buffer source in the Web Audio API? Is there anything like:

`var source=context.createBufferSource();
source.currentTime=5;`

To clarify, I want to play 5 seconds into the audio buffer's audio.

Comment: Have you taken a look here? [HTML audio can't set currentTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37044064/html-audio-cant-set-currenttime)

Comment: @MathiasFalci Thanks for the link, but they're discussing the audio element, not an audio buffer source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`src.start()` takes a second parameter for offset: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/start

`src.start(when,offset,duration)`

If I use `src.start(0,5)`, I'll start the audio buffer 5 seconds in!

Answer (score -1):

If you want an `AudioBufferSourceNode` to start playing from time 5, you have use `src.start(5)` or maybe `src.start(5 + context.currentTime)`.  This assumes that the `AudioBuffer` associated with the `AudioBufferSourceNode` has at least 5 sec of audio to play.  Otherwise you'll hear nothing.

Comment: src.start(x) determines how many seconds we'll wait until playing the sound though, not what time in the sound we'll play from. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/start

However, there is a second parameter that you've made me aware of that does what I want. Thanks! :)