# Updating audio.currentTime resets to 0 - unintended behavior (Django?)

Tags: javascript, django, google-chrome, audio

I'm attempting to update the `currentTime` of an html audio element, however, it keeps resetting to `0` no matter what value I give it.

I've confirmed that the values I'm passing are less than the audio file's duration, and greater that `0`. **The following code works as-intended locally in an html file, but exhibits this strange behavior in my Django app.**

HTML:

```
<audio id="my-audio" preload="true" src="path/to/file.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
```

JavaScript:

```
var audio = document.getElementById('my-audio')
audio.play()
console.log(audio.currentTime) // result: 0.997171 or similar
console.log(audio.duration) // result 3596.06855
audio.currentTime = 500
console.log(audio.currentTime) // result: 0
```

All my other audio-related functions are working. This strange behavior occurs with multiple different audio files. I've searched SO for a solution, but nothing seems relevant to my particular case. I'm thinking that is has something to do with Django's server per [the following comment from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37044064/html-audio-cant-set-currenttime). But I can't find any more information about this.

> I am facing the same issue. It's working on a piece of code, but when i integrate it in a Django application, it fails. It works on Firefox but not on Google Chrome. Video / Audio file doesn't matter, it happens with any file i try on the code. The time i am trying to seek to is less than the duration of the video.

Any help/ tips are greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

* Edit: I can confirm that this is not an issue in Firefox, and this works as intended. I suppose this is an issue specifically with Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling with the same issue. I was uploading media assets to my static directory through django-admin. For some reason (only in chrome) my assets were missing necessary headers: `Accept-Ranges: bytes` and `Content-Range: bytes <some bytes>/<total bytes>`. I could not find a simpler solution, so I routed my file uploads to post to an AWS S3 bucket where I could easily manage permissions/ headers, etc. I followed [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html) and implementation was really easy. To my understanding, this (dedicated hosting of non-static files) is typically what is supposed to happen anyway. I hope no one struggles with this ever again.

Comment: It seems that the issue happens only with Chrome for desktop. Chrome for Android works fine in my case. I hope that will give some ideas to Chrome developers to fix that behaviour.