# Audio current time back to 0 everytime tried to set

Tags: jquery

I use Jquery to play audio on my website.

```
var url = 'path-to-audio';
song = new Audio(url);
song.play();
```

It works very well. Then I create a button to set the position

```
<button onclick="setCurrentTime()">Set now!</button>
```

And its callback

```
function setCurrentTime()
{
    song.currentTime = 100;
}
```

But everytime I click on the button, the audio start from beginning ( currentTime back to 0 !?). I don't know why this happened.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: Does the server that's serving the audio file support streaming?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's on my local

Comment: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37044064/html-audio-cant-set-currenttime) there are some additional answers that may steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Used something like song.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {  this.currentTime = 12; this.play(); }); but it still not working. It just keeps returning to 0