# Drag/Click on Audio Seekbar always pointed back to start of the audio element (React Js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and currently developing the music player using React Js. The idea is to change the seek-bar as the song plays and the user can change the track position using seek-bar(like any other media players). I have the JSX audio tag to play the song and input tag as a seek-bar. Please refer to the below code segments.

```
        {/* audio tag */}
        <audio ref={songRef} type="audio/mpeg" preload="true"
         onTimeUpdate={ e => setCurrentTime(e.target.value) }
         onCanPlay={ e => setDuration(e.target.duration) }
         onEnded={ e => next_song(e, allSong.indexOf(currentSong) + 1, state) }
         src={ currentSong && `${dev_url}${currentSong.id}` }
        />
            
        {/* audio seek-bar */}
        { (currentSong || pSong) && 
         <input type="range" style={styles.progress}
          value={duration ? (currentTime * 100)/duration : 0} 
          onChange={onChangeProgress}/>}
```

Everything works well except the **onChange event on seek-bar**. Every time I triggered the onChange function (i.e; when I'm trying to change the track position using seek-bar), the song goes back to the start (00:00), instead of the desired position. Below is my onChangeHandler which is used to update seek-bar and track position.

```
function onChangeProgress(event) {
       let time = (event.target.value * duration) / 100;
       setCurrentTime(time);
       songRef.current.currentTime = time;
    }
```

I have been stuck here for few days already. Please help me?

Comment: Can you log the value of time in your `onChangeProgress` function to verify it's a valid entry?

Comment: @technicallynick Yes, I can log the time value and it’s valid entry. However, when I tried to log the songRef.current.currentTime at the end of onChangeProgress Function, I always get zero, regardless of time value.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Or even better, create a codesandbox so I can take a look?

Comment: @technicallynick Hi bro, I just found out the root cause. In my case, I was playing the songs, directly from Flask Web Server. The problem is that the client sends **bytes range requests** to the server while seeking to new playback position, and my web server is not configured for those requests. The ideal solution is I need to configure my server for **bytes range requests**. The alternate will be request the song files as a blob, convert into URL objects and play the songs.

Comment: That's great! Glad you were able to pinpoint the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the client seeks to new playback position, it sends the **bytes range requests** to the server, and the server must be able to respond to those requests.

The ideal solution is to configure the web server to accept **bytes range requests** and responds persistant connection.

You can take the status code of request header as a reference to check whether the server is responding persistant connection or not. If the server response is persistant connection, the status code will be ***206 Partial Content**.

*The alternate solution will be getting the audio/song file as a blob type and convert them to ObjectUrl.*

```
const response = await axios.get(url, {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'audio/mp3'
            }
        });
        
        const blob = new Blob([response.data], {
            type: 'audio/mpeg'
        });
        const bloburl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

*Then we can use it as src for audio and play around.*

Please check the below stackoverflow answers for more info.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9565178/13792026
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26865633/13792026
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52520120/13792026